# Subscribe to changes to intermediate objects in a knockoutjs viewmodel

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a large knockout viewModel of which this is a JSON representation:

```
...
existingPlans: {
    startDate: "2014-11-01",
    endDate: "2017-03-01",
    plans: [
        {
            "customTitle": "plan 1 name",
            "monthlyPayments": [ 15000, 15000, 15000, 15000, 15000, 15000 ],
            "futureBalance": [ 90000, 75000, 60000, 45000, 30000, 15000 ]
        },
        {
            "customTitle": "plan 2 name",
            "monthlyPayments": [ 7000, 7000, 7000, 7000 ], 
            "futureBalance": [ 28000, 21000, 14000, 7000 ]
        }
    ]
}
...
```

StartDate and endDate are observables and plans is an observableArray. 
What I'd like to do is create one binding that fires when any of these three observables changes so on the level of "existingPlans".

I could make a computed field that depends on all three, but isn't there an easier way of doing this?

Something like the example below does not work since existingPlans itself cannot be observable (right?)

```
viewModel.existingPlans.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // do stuff with newValue.startDate(), etc
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what should happen when these properties change. If you just want to trigger an event or something similar you could subscribe to the properties and use the same subscription handler for them, like this

```
function ExistingPlans() {
    this.startDate = ko.observable();
    this.endDate = ko.observable();
    this.plans = ko.observableArray();

    this.startDate.subscribe(this.handleChange, this);
    this.endDate.subscribe(this.handleChange, this);
    this.plants.subscribe(this.handleChange, this);                       
}

ExistingPlans.prototype.handleChange = function () {
    // do stuff
};
```

If you need to calculate something or present some result from the value of the properties I would create a computed observable.

Comment: Okay, so I'd have to go through the observable children in any case? Binding to something higher up the JSON tree is not an option?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question. If ExistingPlans entity exists in a parent viewmodel you could subscribe to the properties in a similar way there, like `this.existinPlans.startDate.subscribe(this.handleChange, this)` and add the `handleChange` method to the parent viewmodel instead.

Comment: You cannot just observe the root object, because knockout is observing reference changes, so even if you modify child objects the reference is still the same, so you need to add subscribers to all child items as above

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with three different observables, you can't use a manual subscription. A computed observable is the way to go. A computed observable automatically watches all observables you access, and so will just work:

```
ko.computed(function() {
    // do stuff with existingPlans.startDate(), etc
});
```

If you want to absolutely make sure you're subscribed to all of the observables in a view model, you can use [`ko.toJS`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html):

```
ko.computed(function() {
    ko.toJS(existingPlans);
    // do stuff with existingPlans.startDate(), etc
});
```